# Defining preprocessor macro for certain architecture only

Tags: ios, xcode

By default, Xcode compiles my project for a number of architectures: `arm64`, `armv7` and `armv7s`. Now I want to define a preprocessor macro only for the `arm64` architecture. How can I do that?

Using the `Preprocessor macros` field in Xcode won't work because preprocessor macros in that field will be defined for *all* architectures. But how can I define custom preprocessor macros for certain architectures only?

Comment: You could use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21639128/determine-if-the-device-is-arm64 to detect the architecture and set a #define if you are in arm64 ? Or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39076166/xcode-7-set-preprocessor-macros-per-architecture by editing manually the project file.

Comment: Thanks, but the `arm64` was just an example. I know how to detect 64-bit of course but I generally need to be able to set preprocessor macros for certain architectures, not only for `arm64` so I need a generic solution here. Manually editing the project file seems to do the trick but of course I'd prefer a less intrusive solution if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue, solved something like this (in *.xcodeproj)

```
            HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = (
                "$(PROJECT_DIR)/../../../_result/include",
            );
            "HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS[arch=arm64]" = (
                "$(PROJECT_DIR)/../../../_result/include/iphoneos_arm64",
            );
```